# Large request does not go through web service

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, azure, html-encode

I have asp.net web service , that i send my data through to database.
I am sending texteditor(ckeditor) value which is being encoded by encodeURI.
My web service is on azure. Problem is next , when i send more than ~1200 characters i get request method:GET and status code 404 not found in console, if i send small amounts of text it goes through.

If i copy data(procedure with that data) directly to web service , no mater the size of data , it always goes through.

Where is the problem , is it ajax ? is it something in web service ? or web config for web service , is it azure ?

Thanks for help .

EDIT :  This is an example of the procedure I call and the data I send

```
EXECUTE wsBlogUpdate N'1000030',N'Admin',NULL,N'Name',N'Title',N'Subtitle',N'%3Cp%3ELorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet%2C%20consectetur%20adipiscing%20elit.%20Nunc%20vehicula%20urna%20sed%20mauris%20ultrices%20lacinia.%20Integer%20vel%20justo%20auctor%2C%20accumsan%20nibh%20in%2C%20lacinia%20augue.%20Curabitur%20vel%20dui%20quam.%20Duis%20viverra%20justo%20orci%2C%20ut%20vestibulum%20augue%20pellentesque%20eleifend.%20Duis%20in%20magna%20vulputate%2C%20facilisis%20eros%20et%2C%20viverra%20orci.%20Fusce%20ex%20turpis%2C%20ornare%20ac%20dolor%20ut%2C%20accumsan%20malesuada%20ante.%20Maecenas%20suscipit%20elit%20arcu%2C%20sit%20amet%20pulvinar%20sem%20scelerisque%20dignissim.%20Curabitur%20eget%20luctus%20nibh.%20Maecenas%20interdum%20ut%20nunc%20eget%20hendrerit.%20Fusce%20id%20erat%20condimentum%2C%20iaculis%20est%20luctus%2C%20mattis%20justo.%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3ELorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet%2C%20consectetur%20adipiscing%20elit.%20Nunc%20vehicula%20urna%20sed%20mauris%20ultrices%20lacinia.%20Integer%20vel%20justo%20auctor%2C%20accumsan%20nibh%20in%2C%20lacinia%20augue.%20Curabitur%20vel%20dui%20quam.%20Duis%20viverra%20justo%20orci%2C%20ut%20vestibulum%20augue%20pellentesque%20eleifend.%20Duis%20in%20magna%20vulputate%2C%20facilisis%20eros%20et%2C%20viverra%20orci.%20Fusce%20ex%20turpis%2C%20ornare%20ac%20dolor%20ut%2C%20accumsan%20malesuada%20ante.%20Maecenas%20suscipit%20elit%20arcu%2C%20sit%20amet%20pulvinar%20sem%20scelerisque%20dignissim.%20Curabitur%20eget%20luctus%20nibh.%20Maecenas%20interdum%20ut%20nunc%20eget%20hendrerit.%20Fusce%20id%20erat%20condimentum%2C%20iaculis%20est%20luctus%2C%20mattis%20justo.%3C%2Fp%3E',NULL,N'28.03.2016'
```

Comment: Can you show an example of one of the requests

Comment: @Nkosi Edited with example

Comment: Wait, is it the SQL that fails, or the actual ASMX request?

Comment: @CodingGorilla That is the problem that i dont know , if that long string is shorter , it goes through , but when its that long or longer it doesnt go through ajax call , but if i paste it directly into webService.asmx it goes through

Comment: What do you mean `but if i paste it directly into webService.asmx it goes through`?  How are you doing that?

Comment: @CodingGorilla if i open websiteurl.com/webService/myService.asmx and open my dbService i made and paste it directly there

Comment: So the problem then is somewhere in the code that you use to post the data to your web service, if the test form works (which is what you're describing) then your web service is working properly.  I suggest you post a new question with the details of that posting code following [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to ensure your question does not get closed.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I think my ajax is ok , because it works with all other procedures , just for some reason webService doesnt accept more than 1200 url charachters when it goes through ajax , thanks for your time anyway :)

Comment: Last thought, you might want to make a call with your application (the one that fails) and capture/inspect it with something like fiddler, and then make the same call using the test form that you say works, and compare the two.  That might give you a hint as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was in changing web config and adding

```
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
```